# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object - UNITY SOUNDS

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine

i have got problem with sounds in unity. This is my code:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]
```

public class SoundManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static SoundManager instance;

```
private AudioSource source;
public Dictionary<SOUND_TYPE,AudioClip> sounds;
public enum SOUND_TYPE
{
    DEATCH,
    CATCHED
}

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    source = GetComponent<AudioSource>();

    loadSounds();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{
}

public void playSound(SOUND_TYPE type)
{
    source.clip = sounds[type];
    source.Play();  
}

public void loadSounds()
{
    //loading sounds
    sounds.Add(SOUND_TYPE.DEATCH, Resources.Load<AudioClip>("Sounds/AccelerationLow"));
}
```

}

And i have an error at line with `source.Add()`.

> Error: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object

I don't know what is going on and how can i repair it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a constructor of `sounds`:

```
public Dictionary<SOUND_TYPE,AudioClip> sounds = new Dictionary<SOUND_TYPE,AudioClip>();
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that `public Dictionary<SOUND_TYPE,AudioClip> sounds` is not initialized or has the value of null initialized. To initialize this dictionary create a constructor or initialize this dictionary in the start method sinds the source is initialized there to.

To initialize an empty dictionary use:

`Dictionary<SOUND_TYPE,AudioClip> sounds = new Dictionary<SOUND_TYPE,AudioClip>();`

```
void Start()
{
    source = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    sounds = new Dictionary<SOUND_TYPE,AudioClip>();`
    loadSounds();
}

public void loadSounds()
{
  Start()
  //loading sounds
  sounds.Add(SOUND_TYPE.DEATCH, Resources.Load<AudioClip>("Sounds/AccelerationLow"));

}
```